# Compile Linux program from Mac OS X with Free Pascal

Tags: freepascal

I want to build a command-line tool in Free Pascal for run in a [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions) 9.

This is a production server, and it is hard get approved to install anything apart from this tool.

I code on [Mac OS X Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) and wonder if is possible cross-compile from here to Linux?

The server run on [Xeon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Success! If you install [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) and then say

```
sudo fink install fpc-i386-linux
```

it will install Free Pascal and everything you need to cross compile. You will then be able to say

```
/sw/bin/fpc -Tlinux hw.pas
```

and get a Linux executable.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are cross-compilation options I can't find, you're probably out of luck doing it directly from Mac OS X. However, you can get what you want by installing a virtual machine like [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) or Sun's [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/), installing SUSE on it, and compiling there.

Answer (score 1):

There are now `.dmg` files of Free Pascal (binary, source, and [Lazarus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28IDE%29)) available for install, so it should be easy to install, open, and compile it. Note, though, that if it links to Linux-specific `.so` files, that they may need to be installed on Mac OS X, or you will have to change the code not to use them.

Answer (score 0):

FPC can crosscompile pretty well in general. There are limitations though:

1. Crosscompiling from a non x86/x86_64 architecture to x86/x86_64 won't work. It requires extended, which isn't emulated on other archs. However you seem to use an intel OS X machine (not PPC), so that doesn't apply.
2. Depending on the libraries used and the nature of the target platforms you might need to have target-libraries on host.  (in general: not for windows, but you will have to for *nix/OS X as target)

See also http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/buildfaq.pdf  it contains some background on crosscompiling with FPC.